# Trying to duplicate flexible banner as seen in video

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Im trying to duplicate something like what is shown in the video. I have 2 blocks of div. One containing a random image and another a video and im trying to make them flexible and identical as possible to the video. How can I approach this?

I tried using flex box to align them horizontally then media query them to go vertically when the width of window is smaller. However I cannot get it to shrink like the one in the video.

Html code im not gonna upload because its just a container div with image and video div inside it.

```
Here is my css : 

.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  height: 45vh;
  width: 70vh;
}


.video {
  height: 45vh;
  width: 70vh;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice to see someone who shares love for dota like me. Can you share some code, please?

Comment: just added it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I made max-width 900 for sake of demo on codepen, you can now tweak them.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
}


.item {width:50%}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
   display:block;
  }
.item {width:100%}

}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
 <div class="item"><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
<div class="item"><img class="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <div class="image"> <img src="./myimage.png"></img> </div>
       <div class="video"> <video src="./videoplayback.mp4"></video> </div>

    </div>
  
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have setup the HTML as you described and the css goes as follow:

```
.container {
  /* max-width: 1400px; */
   width: 90vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image   {
  /* height: 45vh;
  width: 70vh; */
  width: 50%;
}

.image img  {
  /* height: 45vh;
  width: 70vh; */
  width: 100%;
}


.video  {
  /* height: 45vh;
  width: 70vh; */
  width:50%
}


.video video {
  /* height: 45vh;
  width: 70vh; */
  width:100%
}


@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container { 
    display: block ;
  } */

}
```

explanation:

Set the container's width to 90% of the viewport's width and then give the image and video divs 50% width(which will be  50% of its parent or of that 90% in this case). In the media quire just set the display of the container to `block`. I really didn't know what the height of the image or video should have been so I have left it for you to decide on that.

Comment: https://replit.com/@HaroonAzhar/MadeupSlategrayGzip . Link to the  Repl for demo.